# How to map() when state "selectedOptions2" triggered

Tags: reactjs

i need you to look for bug my code. I know it is something wrong.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { options1, options2, questions } from "./data";
import Select from "react-select";

class Esensial extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedOption: [],
      selectedOption2: []
    };
  }

  handleChange1 = selectedOption => {
   this.setState({ selectedOption, selectedOption2: null });
  };

  handleChange2 = selectedOption => {
   this.setState({ selectedOption2: selectedOption });
  };
filteredOptions() {
    return options2.filter(o => o.link === 
this.state.selectedOption.value);
  }
  questionsOptions() {
    return questions.filter(
      question => question.link === this.state.selectedOption2.value
    );
  }
  render() {
    const filteredOptions = this.filteredOptions();
    const questionsOptions = this.questionsOptions();

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>UKM Esensial</h1>

        <div className="form-group">
          <label>Pilih Jenis Upaya Pelayanan Kesehatan</label>
          <Select
            className="form-control"
            isClearable={false}
            onChange={this.handleChange1}
            options={options1}
            value={this.state.selectedOption}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label>Pilih Variable</label>
          <Select
            className="form-control"
            isClearable
            onChange={this.handleChange2}
            options={filteredOptions}
            value={this.state.selectedOption2}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <table className="table table-striped">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Sub-Variabel</th>
                <th>Sasaran</th>
                <th>Capaian</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {questionsOptions.map(q => (
                <tr>
                  <td>{q}</td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="number" />
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <input type="number" />
                  </td>
                </tr>
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Esensial;
```

the code will run, when selectedOption get a value it will filter() the options2, when selectedOption2 get a value it will filter() the questionsOptions, but i don't know the code still crash.. help me please..
is it wrong with the map?
may be because i don't use componentDidUpdate(){}.
somehow when i use componentDidUpdate(), it execute by itself. maybe i use firebaseauth() to authenticate the login system.

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: @zsgomori it said "Cannot read property 'value' of null",                            
    question => question.link === this.state.selectedOption2.value

Comment: hello, i have found the answer. it should be handleChange1 = selectedOption => {
    this.setState({ selectedOption, selectedOption2: [] });
  }; . thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of `this.state.selectedOption2.value`, as you are setting value of `selectedOption2` in `handleChange1` null. Following can be solutions:

```
questionsOptions() {
  const {selectedOption2} = this.state;
return questions.filter(
  question => question.link === selectedOption2 && selectedOption2.value || ''
);
}
```

From your initial state I am assuming that `selectedOption2` is array so you cannot access value as `selectedOption2.value` you have to access by index e.g `selectedOption2[0].value`(assuming 0 in the required index)

Answer (score 0):

Your state is a bit confusing, because you've initialized them as arrays, but you'd like to access them as objects. The error message evinces that *selectedOption2* doesn't own any property called *value*.

The answer strongly depends on what you expect to get when the *onChange* method is effected on.

I don't know your exact data structures, but if you're working with arrays, then the filter functions should be something similar to this:

```
questionsOptions() {
   return questions.filter(
      question => {
         this.state.selectedOption2.map(option => {
            return question === option.value;
         });
      }
   );
}
```

In the aforementioned example, I assume that *selectedOption2* is an array of objects, therefore you should use the *map* function in order to find the corresponding value that is expected.

By the way, if it's a simple value - i.e. it's a string, integer etc. -, then you should leave the *value* property on the right side of the comparison in your example.

```
questionsOptions() {
   return questions.filter(
      question => question === this.state.selectedOption2
   );
}
```

On the contrary, if it's an array with simple values, then:

```
questionsOptions() {
   return questions.filter(
      question => {
         this.state.selectedOption2.map(option => {
            return question === option;
         });
      }
   );
}
```

I'd also propose to look into your data structures and think about how the state field should be initialized, since it's quite misleading and causes impediments both for the readers and you.